# How to extract a complex version number using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, centos

I use sed in CentOs to extract version number and it's work fine:

`echo "var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-4.1.56.war" | sed -nre 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+).*/\1/p'`

But my problem is that i am not able to extract when the version is shown like this:

*var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-4.1.56-RC1.war*

I want to extract the **4.1.56-RC1** if it is present.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT 2**

Ok to be clear take this example, with a path:

Sometimes the path contains only a serial number like this var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-**4.1.56**.war and sometimes it contains a series of numbers and letters like this "var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-**4.1.56-RC1**.war

The need is to recover either **4.1.56** or **4.1.56-RC1**  depending on the version present in the path. With sed or grep, no preference.

This seems to work but the .war is shown at the end:

```
echo "var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-4.1.56.war" | egrep -o '[0-9]\S*'
```

Comment: why don't you just say `echo "version ..." | awk '{print $2}'`?

Comment: because maybe the extract is make from a path like this: /var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-4.1.56-RC1.war

Comment: update your question with the full input.

Comment: I'm going to vote close based "__Unclear what you're asking__" This question will be of no help to future users if you don't update it.

Comment: ok, the update it's done

Comment: @Marc wrt `because maybe the extract is make from a path like this: /var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-4.1.56-RC1.war` - so what if it was? Don't answer that in a comment but instead edit your question to show examples of all possible version info formats that you want to be able to handle **along with the expected output for each**.

Comment: How about test-marc2soapp-1.0.00.war and test-4everapp-4.3.03-fix4.war ? Can I write the requirements as: When the input has spaces, keep everything between first and second space. If not, cut after app- and the last 4 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `(-[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)` to your regex:

```
echo "Version 4.2.4 (test version)" | sed -nre 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)).*/\1/p'
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your code and I modified as follows for my needs: `echo "/var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-4.1.56-RC1.war" | sed -nre 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*)*).*/\1/p'`

Answer (score 1):

Little unclear what you are after, but this seems to be in the general direction.

Given:

```
$ echo "$e"
/var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-4.1.56-RC1.war
/var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-RC1.war
Version 4.2.4 (test version)
```

Try:

```
$ echo "$e" | egrep -o '(\d+\.\d+\.\d+-?\w*)'
4.1.56-RC1
4.2.4
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will match the first digit up to 2 digits in length ({1,2}, second up to 2 digits and the last up to 4 digits followed by anything non-space up to a space.

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,2\}.[0-9]\{1,2\}.[0-9]\{1,4\}'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just using whitespace as the delimiter like

```
echo "Version 4.2.4-RC1 (test version)" | grep -Po "Version\s+\K\S+"
```

for grep `-P` says to use Perl style regex, `-o` shows only the matching part and the `\K` in the string says not to show everything before it as part of the match

Comment: it's good idea but maybe the extract is make from a path like this: /var/opt/test/war/test-webapp-4.1.56-RC1.war. It's not the same format each timee

Comment: In that case, is it reliable that it's always the 3rd and alter in the last part? Could you do something like `basename <path> | cut -f 3- -d- | cut -f1 -d.`

Answer (score 0):

This passes both tests

```
egrep -o '[0-9]\S*'
```

Unfortunately, not all greps support `-o`, but grep in Linux does.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Version 4.2.4 (test version)" | sed 's/Version[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:](]*\).*/\1/'
```

But like every extraction, you need to define what you want, not what could exist and extract it (or change your request).